# R time series customized x-axis, but y-axis is gone

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I have a rather simple problem here:

I customized my x-axis, but somehow the y-axis is completely gone.
How can I bring it back?

```
    zoo.vol<-as.zoo(data)
    times<-seq(start(zoo.vol),end(zoo.vol),by="year")
    plot(x = zoo.vol,ylab = "Volatility", main = "my title", at=times, format="%Y",col = tsRainbow,screens = 1,axt="n")
```

My zoo.vol looks like this:

```
structure(c(0.0151487553475412, 0.0145973941978265, 0.0147267840693453, 
            0.0160134529429522, 0.0154340940175316, 0.0148705095898274, 0.0144180796103523, 
            0.0156263569934272, 0.0150973775246807, 0.0158179328705817, 0.0124984401178442, 
            0.0118049612119821, 0.0118113562642818, 0.0116271323991807, 0.0110968729656786, 
            0.0106359654383497, 0.0134419598568456, 0.0126830764652812, 0.0121315673959188, 
            0.0127575642807472, 0.0100602793776595, 0.00965703285524349, 
            0.00946107070266373, 0.00966515004638001, 0.00987951140648287, 
            0.0095523581423164, 0.0108939716700509, 0.010706535594705, 0.0102804827502289, 
            0.0112660905807839), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
                                                                     c("A", "B", "C")), index = structure(c(10595, 10596, 10597, 
                                                                                                            10598, 10599, 10602, 10603, 10604, 10605, 10606), class = "Date"), class = "zoo")
```

So there are three charts on one graph.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A `dput(zoo.vol)` (and possibly more than a `head` amount would be helpful. I'm also not sure what you mean by "completely gone" (can you post an image? If SO won't let you post an image, just post the URL and someone will, no doubt, make the graph visible).

Comment: data provided. There is ticks/unit on the y-axis. It's just blank. If you run the data, I think you'll know what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't provided `tsRainbow`, but regardless, none of `at`, `format`, nor `axt` are arguments to `plot.zoo`, as indicated by the warnings that your code returns.

Comment: I know, but it somehow worked. It's not really right. How can I customize the x-axis the way I did and also keep the y-axis marks? tsRainbow is just color param. it's not important in this regards. thank you.

Comment: Try `plot(zoo.vol, ylab = "Volatility", main = "my title", at=times, format="%Y",col = tsRainbow,screens = 1,axt="n")`

Comment: I don't see any difference from your suggestion. Did you change any thing?

Comment: Suppress the x-axis with `xaxt='n'`, then see `?axis.Date`.

Comment: One simple change would be to be to issue `library(lattice)` and then replace the word `plot` with `xyplot` keeping all the arguments the same.  That will invoke `xyplot.zoo` which uses lattice's algorithms rather than `plot.zoo` which uses classic graphic's algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs. I've tried all of the above mentioned suggestions. However, I still can't get it to work. A workable solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: As I indicated above, `at`, `format`, and `axt` aren't arguments to `plot.zoo`. Start with `plot(x = zoo.vol,ylab = "Volatility", main = "my title", screens = 1)`, and tell us how the result fails to meet your requirements. This type of question really requires that you provide a clear description of your desired output, and how your code fails to achieve it. You've told us your y-axis is "gone", but if you omit the invalid arguments, the axis plots as I would expect.

Comment: Then, if you want to have a custom x-axis, suppress the x-axis with `plot(x = zoo.vol,ylab = "Volatility", main = "my title", screens = 1, xaxt='n')`, and plot the axis with `axis.Date(1, at=times)`.